# Deleting an array element with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with several elements. The array keys are numeric.

I now want to remove a certain element. All I know is the element's content, not the key.

Is there an easy way to remove this element from the array?
Or do I need to loop through all elements of the array to get the key and then unset the element with that key?

Comment: for the several elements it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [array search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function to get the key

```
$key = array_search('searchterm', $items); 
unset($items[$key]);
```

Comment: Just be sure to check the return value for `array_search` (see my answer below)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) to remove all elements with that particular value:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($val) { return $val !== 'some value'; });
```

This example uses an [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) that were introduced with PHP 5.3. But you can use any other [callback function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Or you can use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) to get the keys of all elements with that value and do a diff on the keys after:

```
$arr = array_diff_key($arr, array_flip(array_keys($arr, 'some value', true)));
```

Comment: +1: didn't know the `array_filter` function, seems to be really handy.

Comment: @nico array_filter seems overkill if you have unique elements in your array. it will loop through all elements. And array_flip will spoil your data if there are non-unique elements. Both solutions are funny, but impractical. Being not an actor, but a programmer, always make your code as easy and readable as possible. You'll lave to read it in the future. So, your own one is way better.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: The complexity of both `array_search` and `array_filter` is O(n). And `array_flip` is only applied of an array of keys; so there won’t be any information loss.

Comment: @Gumbo, Dont worry, here is another +1, for a great answer.

Comment: array_search would stop at first occurrence. And array_filter wouldn't. Second is o.k., by bad. But it's still way overkill and obfuscated. But yeah don't worry, you'll get your upvotes anyway.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Yes, the average behavior is O(n/2) for `array_search` versus Θ(n) for `array_filter`; but it’s still O(n) in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

sure

```
foreach($myarray as $key=>$item) {
    if($item=='myknowncontent') { unset($myarray[$key]; }
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I mentioned. I was just wondering if I could unset the element without looping through all elements of the array.

Comment: As Col. Shrapnel said `for the several elements it doesn't really matter`

Comment: @Starx. Wow you got me, I am not a Native English Speaker. Then... What..(Your Point)

Comment: Nothing, just did not understand the meaning of the sentence you quoted, that's all! :)

Comment: @nico you have to loop through all elements only if they aren't unique. otherwise you can use `break` operator.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: OK, now it makes more sense :) Sorry, didn't understand your first sentence.

Comment: @nico... Oh, me too, :) Sorry, I also didn't understand your sentence

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the corresponding key:

```
$key = array_search("whatever", $array);
if ($key !== FALSE)
   unset($array[$key]);
```

Comment: This will remove `$array[0]` if there is no element with such value.